# How to return a filename when user clicks button in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

This is a crude way to do it BUT I'm trying to get this 
model attribute "file" into the PostMapping "getfile" so that when the user clicks "Submit", they are directed to the file associated with that button.

I've seen many webpages telling me th:value will insert the desired text into the form field... it's not working for me.

In the end, I'm just trying to send the user to the file they click on.

Template:

```
<table>

    <tr><th>File Name</th>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each="file : ${filedata}">

        <td>

            <form action="#" th:action="@{~/home/ebay/getfile}" method="post" th:object="${filetobind}">
<!--                               th:field maps to object       -->
                <input type="text" th:field="*{fileName}" th:value="#{file.fileName}" th:text="${file.fileName}"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Get" />
            </form>

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(Mappings.FILES)
    public String getDirectory(Model model){

        model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.FILE_DATA, fileService.getDirectory());
        model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.FILE, new DirectoryFile());


        // debug
        System.out.println("#############################################################");
        for(DirectoryFile file : fileService.getDirectory()){

            System.out.println(file.getFilePath());
        }
        System.out.println("#############################################################");


        return ViewNames.DIRECTORY;
    }


    @PostMapping("getfile")
    public String getFile(Model model, @ModelAttribute(AttributeNames.FILE) DirectoryFile file ){


        System.out.println("Filepath:" + file.getFileName());

        //model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.FILE, file.getFileName().trim());

        return "data/" + file.getFileName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at your input

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{fileName}" th:value="#{file.fileName}" th:text="${file.fileName}"/>
```

On form submission, you are sending the controller the value of your input in an attribute called "fileName" inside your object "filetobind", this happens because of how you defined `th:field` and the form `th:object`, and it's fine.

Now, for the th:value part and why it isn't working for you: The syntax `#{...}` is for externalizing text literals in files so you make your html more "generic", quoting from the documentation:

> Externalizing text is extracting fragments of template code out of
>   template files so that they can be kept in specific separate files
>   (typically .properties files) and that they can be easily substituted
>   by equivalent texts written in other languages (a process called
>   internationalization or simply i18n). Externalized fragments of text
>   are usually called “messages”.
>
> Messages have always a key that identifies them, and Thymeleaf allows
>   you to specify that a text should correspond to a specific message
>   with the #{...} syntax

So those are good for labels, for example, but not input contents (input values).

Now since it is a text input, you can either ommit the `th:value` part and let the user fill the input, or you can give it a value with the syntax `${...}`, which access a variable passed from the controller. Quoting the doc:

> The ${today} expression simply means “get the variable called today”,
>   but these expressions could be more complex (like ${user.name} for
>   “get the variable called user, and call its getName() method”).

Change the value for `th:value="${file.fileName}"` and you should be fine (as long as you provide the file variable from the controller).